# OTP verification using javascript and firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication

I AM making a otp verification by phone and email, using javascript and firebase.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.btn-verify,
.btn-continue {
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffdc3d;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.container-content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 580px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile-verify,
.otp-container,
.box-verify {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.otp-container,
.mobile-verify {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px #e2e2e2;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.otp-container .nav,
.mobile-verify .nav {
    position: relative;
}

.otp-container .nav p,
.mobile-verify .nav p {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.otp-container .text p,
.mobile-verify .text p {
    color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
}

.otp-container .keyboard,
.mobile-verify .keyboard {
    margin: 0 -4px;
}

.otp-container .keyboard .num,
.otp-container .keyboard .remove,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .num,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .remove {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: calc(33.3333% - 8px);
    margin: 0 4px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.otp-container .keyboard .num:hover,
.otp-container .keyboard .num.active,
.otp-container .keyboard .remove:hover,
.otp-container .keyboard .remove.active,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .num:hover,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .num.active,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .remove:hover,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .remove.active {
    background-color: rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.8);
}

.otp-container .keyboard .num-n,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .num-n {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.otp-container .keyboard .num-n:hover,
.mobile-verify .keyboard .num-n:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.mobile-verify {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    z-index: 5;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.mobile-verify .text p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mobile-verify .keyboard {
    margin-top: auto;
}

.mobile-verify .phone-num-input {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.mobile-verify .phone-num-input label {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.mobile-verify .phone-num-input .form-input input {
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #e7e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.mobile-verify .phone-num-input .form-input input:focus {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.mobile-verify .text-danger {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.otp-container .nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.otp-container .nav i {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.otp-container .nav i:hover {
    color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.7);
}

.otp-container .nav p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.otp-container .otp-input .input {
    width: 25%;
    height: 51px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.8);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.otp-container .otp-input .input:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.otp-container .resend-code {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.otp-container .btn-resend {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.otp-container .btn-resend:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.otp-container .text-danger {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mobile-verify.go-right {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.otp-container.go-right {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.box-verify {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 15;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    transition: transform 0.4 cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.box-verify i {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.box-verify p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box-verify p span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.box-verify .btn-return {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box-verify.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <title>Project Create OTP - HTML/SCSS/JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="container-content">
        <div class="mobile-verify go-right active-box">
            <div class="nav d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <p>Mobile Verification</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    Please enter your mobile <br />number to verify your
                    account
                </p>
                <p>You'll receive a 4 digit code <br />to verify</p>
            </div>
            <div class="phone-num-input">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="phone-number">Enter your phone</label>
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="phone-number" />
                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
            <button id="btn-continue" class="btn btn-continue">Send OTP</button>
            <div class="keyboard d-flex flex-wrap">
                <span class="num-1 num" data-key="1">1</span>
                <span class="num-2 num" data-key="2">2</span>
                <span class="num-3 num" data-key="3">3</span>
                <span class="num-4 num" data-key="4">4</span>
                <span class="num-5 num" data-key="5">5</span>
                <span class="num-6 num" data-key="6">6</span>
                <span class="num-7 num" data-key="7">7</span>
                <span class="num-8 num" data-key="8">8</span>
                <span class="num-9 num" data-key="9">9</span>
                <span class="num-n num"></span>
                <span class="num-0 num" data-key="0">0</span>
                <span class="remove" data-key="backspace"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="otp-container go-right">
            <div class="nav d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="btn-back fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                <p>Verification Code</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    Please type the verification <br />
                    code sent to
                    <span class="phone">+8412345***</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    The OTP will expire in
                    <span class="expire text-dark">30s</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="otp-input d-flex">
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="input" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="input" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="input" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="input" />
            </div>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
            <button id="btn-verify" class="btn btn-verify d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                Verify now <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="resend-code text-muted">
                Didn't receive code?
                <span class="btn-resend text-danger">Request again</span>
            </div>
            <div class="keyboard d-flex flex-wrap">
                <span class="num-1 num" data-key="1">1</span>
                <span class="num-2 num" data-key="2">2</span>
                <span class="num-3 num" data-key="3">3</span>
                <span class="num-4 num" data-key="4">4</span>
                <span class="num-5 num" data-key="5">5</span>
                <span class="num-6 num" data-key="6">6</span>
                <span class="num-7 num" data-key="7">7</span>
                <span class="num-8 num" data-key="8">8</span>
                <span class="num-9 num" data-key="9">9</span>
                <span class="num-n num"></span>
                <span class="num-0 num" data-key="0">0</span>
                <span class="remove" data-key="backspace"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-verify">
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 
    <script src="./app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-auth.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyD60SY0uo_n_MoLZAiK2R4KfePCqzrZwYA",
            authDomain: "otp-ver-3c9e0.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://otp-ver-3c9e0-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "otp-ver-3c9e0",
            storageBucket: "otp-ver-3c9e0.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "370199553240",
            appId: "1:370199553240:web:106d83cc34bcc0bd9863ad",
            measurementId: "G-99B00XQFPG"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const auth = getAuth(app);


        const otpContainer = document.querySelector('.otp-container');
        const mobileVerify = document.querySelector('.mobile-verify');
        const boxVerify = document.querySelector('.box-verify');
        const btnContinue = document.querySelector('.btn-continue');
        const btnResend = document.querySelector('.btn-resend');
        const btnVerify = document.querySelector('.btn-verify');
        const btnBack = document.querySelector('.btn-back');
        const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone-number');
        const otpInput = document.querySelectorAll('.otp-input .input');
        const containerContent = document.querySelector('.container-content');
        const expireEle = document.querySelector('.expire');

        // OTP
        let expire = 30;
        let OTP;
        let countdown;
        let yourInputNumber = '';


        btnContinue.addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
                'size': 'normal',
                'callback': (response) => {
                    // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
                    // ...
                },
                'expired-callback': () => {
                    // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
                    // ...
                }
            }, auth);

            recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId) => {
                window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
            });
            const phonenumber = "+91" + phoneNumber.value
            const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

            signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phonenumber, appVerifier)
                .then((confirmationResult) => {
                    // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
                    // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
                    window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
                    // ...
                }).catch((error) => {
                    // Error; SMS not sent
                    // ...
                });

        })


        btnVerify.onclick = function () {
            confirmationResult.confirm(otpinput.value).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var userobj = response.user;
                var token = userobj.xa;
                var provider = "phone";
                var email = phoneNumber.value;
                if (token != null && token != undefined && token != "") {
                    sendDatatoServerPhp(email, provider, token, email);
                }
            })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }

    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

now this is causing this error[POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=AIzaSyD60SY0uo_n_MoLZAiK2R4KfePCqzrZwYA 400][1]
and not sending otp to the desired number

kindly check the image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/obuls.png

Comment: Try changing the catch to `.catch((error) => console.log(error))` so you can see the error in console. Also please do share a screenshot of the response from the network tab.

Comment: assert.ts:161 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
    at j (assert.ts:161:7)
    at q (assert.ts:264:19)
    at zn.init (recaptcha_verifier.ts:256:16)
    at zn.makeRenderPromise (recaptcha_verifier.ts:237:28)
    at zn.render (recaptcha_verifier.ts:171:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:167:31)